# Ubuntu 14.04 Dell Inspiron 15R - unable to adjust brightness

Tags: 14.04, dell, brightness, inspiron

When trying to adjust brightness on my Dell Inspiron 15R, I see the brightness icon moving up or down, but the actual brightness remains the same.

Answer (score 4):

I am using Dell Inspiron 15R N5520 with dual boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

1. Run the command below in terminal to know what video card is used for the backlight/brightness:

   ```
   ls /sys/class/backlight/
   ```

   If your graphics card is Intel, you can proceed with the fix below.
2. Open a terminal and create the following configuration file, if it does not exist:

   ```
   sudo touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
   ```

   Now we need to edit this file. You can use any editor be it a terminal one or graphical.

   ```
   sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
   ```

   Add the following lines to this file:

   ```
   Section "Device"        
       Identifier  "card0"        
       Driver      "intel"
       Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"        
       BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
   EndSection
   ```

   Save it.
3. Log out and log in back. The brightness control should be working through function keys now.

Comment: This worked For me :)

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved when I upgraded to 14.10

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small script which I use to control the brightness.  Basically you want to poke a value into `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`.  The max value can be found in `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness`

My simple script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

---

An alternate answer is suggested by [itsfoss](http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/), however I had to modify it slightly as the pci bus ID seems to have changed since Ubuntu 13.10:

Create the file `20-intel.conf`

`sudo touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`

Edit the file so that the contents are

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:02:0"
EndSection
```

Comment: I don't believe this is a proper solution but a workaround. Perhaps if my answer doesn't work we can use this information from your script to fix it. I do, however, think the solution lies in changing GRUB's configuration.

Comment: I haven't tried the acpi-backlight solution yet - my Dell does not seem to respond well to the acpi kernel parameters.  [Itsfoss](http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/) had a solution which worked off and on depending upon the recent updates, but because of the intermittent nature of that fix I've resorted to my somewhat simplistic solution.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste In my continuing frustration with the backlight issue, I tries the `acpi_backlight=vendor` parameter - this prevents my Dell from booting, unfortunately.  I have found that the brightness adjustment keys do work until either the screen turns off (idle activity) or the system is suspended.  Logging out and back in restores the functionality.

Comment: So, you were able to remove the acpi_backlight=vendor part, right? I wasn't sure because your computer won't boot so how would you change the config file and update GRUB? Anyway, if that causes boot problems I don't really don't know what to do. Are you using GRUB or GRUB 2? I think it's pretty strange that your computer isn't working well, because I've done some Googling and Dell has some compatibility tests with your computer and Ubuntu 12.04 and found that it is 100% Ubuntu compatible. http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201010-6645/ Why does acpi_backlight=vendor prevent booting?

Comment: Haven't checked into the why of that before - generally when doing kernel boot changes I edit grub on the fly - press 'e' during the grub boot menu and you can change the boot items.  This is a temporary change, lasting only until the next boot - handy for testing something.

Comment: Checked your Dell link - the problem is that Dell make a number of computers and calls them 15R - the computer as described is not mine!

Answer (score 0):

I realize you don't have a Gateway NE56R, but there is a solution (source: http://talegari.wikidot.com/blog:14) that may help you. If it doesn't, just undo the changes. First, open a terminal and type `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`. You will (hopefully) see two lines: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite_splice` and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="".` I want you to comment them both out by putting a # at the beginning of each of the two lines. Then put the following line (not commented!) underneath:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Once you are done doing that, close gedit, and run one more command in the terminal:

`sudo update-grub` and reboot. If it works, hooray! If not, open up the file, uncomment the two lines, remove the line I told you to put in, close it, run `sudo update-grub` and reboot to undo what we have done. This is a little hardware compatibility bug that is fixed in 14.10 Utopic Unicorn, which doesn't come out until late October.